# Lucene: Building a query of single terms

Tags: lucene

I'm new to Lucene and I would like to know what's the difference (if there is any) between

```
PhraseQuery.add(Term1)
PhraseQuery.add(Term2)
PhraseQuery.add(Term3)
```

and

```
term1 = new TermQuery(new Term(...));
booleanQuery.add(term1, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);    

term2 = new TermQuery(new Term(...));
booleanQuery.add(term2, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

term3 = new TermQuery(new Term(...));
booleanQuery.add(term3, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `PhraseQuery` requires that all the terms exist in the field being searched.
- Your `BooleanQuery` does not require that all the terms exist.

This leads to the question of what is the difference between your `PhraseQuery` and:

```
term1 = new TermQuery(new Term(...));
booleanQuery.add(term1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);    

term2 = new TermQuery(new Term(...));
booleanQuery.add(term2, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

term3 = new TermQuery(new Term(...));
booleanQuery.add(term3, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

The difference here is that the `PhraseQuery` would require the terms be in the correct order, as opposed to the `BooleanQuery` which would not have any particular order requirement.

Comment: So, roughly speaking, each term in PhraseQuery always has the MUST property and he order is fixed. Then I will definitely go with BooleanQuery. What about the strings parsing (in order to add the terms to booleanQuery) ? Should I do it manually or can I use Lucene ? thanks

Comment: @Patrick You can parse the input text using Lucene by taking advantage of one of the existing analyzers or writing your own.  Generally speaking, you should use the same analyzer to both build your index and construct your query. http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html